# Dynamic helper cell for list of combined values

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-formula, office365

**Update:**

In essence if have the fomrula:
`=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>'",TRUE,CHOOSE({1,2},IF((A2:A100="")+(A2:A100="-"),"",A2:A100),IF((B2:B100="")+(B2:B100="-"),"","-")))&"</s></t>","//s"),"'","")`

This combines column A and B in a specific order. Is it possible to modify this formula such that instead of a hyphen the letter above is repeated as in column E in the image.

---

**Background**
In the image below have made up data in columns A and B (raw materials and sub components) that is sorted /combined in a specific order in column C. In column D I have created a helper column which in affect 'groups' the raw materials and sub components.

[image]

The formula for this helper column is:

`=INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(ROW(A2:A15),IF(A2:A20<>"",ROW(A2:A20),"")))`

The problem I have is that ideally the helper column should group all parts of the 'group' after they are combined. Essentially I am trying to make a helper column +1 every time the group changes. i.e. instead of just `AAA for a,b,c` its `AAAA for A,a,b,c` or instead of `C for g` its `CC for C and g` etc. So in essence its that same as the orriginal helper column but contains an extra value for each.

If anyone knows anyways in which I can achieve this it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to `LAMBDA()`?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got so messy....hopefully someone else can help you out:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=LET(X,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s"),Y,FREQUENCY(IF(X="-",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X))),IF(X="-",0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X)))),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,REPT(FILTER(A2:A15&"</s><s>",A2:A15<>""),FILTER(Y,Y>0)+1))&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']"))
```

Without `LET()`:

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,REPT(FILTER(A2:A15&"</s><s>",A2:A15<>""),FILTER(FREQUENCY(IF(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")="-",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")))),IF(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")="-",0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s"))))),FREQUENCY(IF(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")="-",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")))),IF(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")="-",0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s")))))>0)+1))&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']")
```

Comment: Hi, ill give this ago but again I'm having problems because I dont have the LET function. So far I have `=FILTER((FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,IF(COLUMN(A2:B15)=2,"-",IF(A2:B15="","",A2:B15)))&"</s></t>","//s"),Y,FREQUENCY(IF(X="-",SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X))),IF(X="-",0,SEQUENCE(COUNTA(X)))),FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",,REPT(FILTER(A2:A15&"</s><s>",A2:A15<>""),FILTER(Y,Y>0)+1))&"</s></t>","//s[.!='']")),,)` but there is some error with this.

Comment: @Nick, without `LET()` it's getting ugly very quick. I've updated the answer.

Comment: If you're interested I did find a simpler solution to this, although it isnt dynamic.

`=IFERROR(FILTER($A$3:$A$101,$A$3:$A$101=D6),I5)`

Comment: Yeah offcourse there are simpler solutions but I thought you were specifically looking for dynamic helper =)

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(C1="","",IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(C1,A:A),0)),OFFSET(D1,-1,,,)))`
and drag down.
EXACT makes the match function find case sensitive match (to be true). If not found show the value from the cell above (offset -1 row).

Comment: HI, unfortunately I cant use Case to separate the two. Annoyingly I did write this in my question but removed it. Also it would be helpful if it were dynamic. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite a simple solution although it isnt dynamic.

=IFERROR(FILTER($A$3:$A$101,$A$3:$A$101=D6),I5)